What was different, spending-wise, between the first version of the December 2024 budget deal and the second one proposed by Trump?
This question isn't about the approval mechanism or the need for the spending bill.  Rather it is about the specifics in which Trump v2 (which has failed, with a vote pending on Trump v3) differed from the spending items in the original, v1, bi-partisan plan.
What is this all about, $-wise?
Presumably, aside from political drama, some of this also about the budget, so I find the press coverage of the budgetary specifics rather lightweight, leaning much more on coverage of the political significance and possible results of a governmental shutdown.
From the coverage below, I saw that Trump wanted to eliminate the debt ceiling.  There are other mentions in the press of $100B in aid monies.  But those are apparently for US internal aid, not foreign aid, and includes hurricane damage relief.  Is that what is actually getting cut by Trump?  Especially since some/most of the hurricane damage areas are in Red states.
Trump-backed bill to keep US government running fails to pass

The latest spending plan was the second in as many days which failed to reach the two-thirds majority needed to pass the lower chamber of Congress, with 38 Republicans voting against the bill on Thursday night.


This was in defiance of Trump who the day before had thwarted a previous cross-party funding deal that the Republican House leadership had struck with Democrats, after heavy criticism of the measure by tech billionaire Elon Musk.


After Musk drummed up opposition for the spending bill, Trump and the incoming vice-president JD Vance dealt the final blow to Republican House Speaker Mike Johnson's deal on Wednesday evening.


They said in a joint statement they wanted streamlined legislation without the Democratic-backed provisions that Johnson had included.


They also called for Congress to raise or eliminate the debt ceiling, which determines how much the government can borrow to pay its bills, and limit the funding legislation to temporary spending and disaster relief.

p.s. I know why that spending bill is, oddly enough, asking for a 2 year suspension of the debt ceiling - to make room for Trump tax cuts.  This question is really more focussed on the spending side of things.  What is getting cut out or added?

FYI, v3 passed the House tonight and is expected to pass the Senate. I think it's basically v2 without raising the debt ceiling.

The dollar cost to the federal government difference between the two bills is about $ 0.25 billion, in a bill that includes three months of the basically entire non-defense discretionary budget (about $900 billion dollars) and also $110 billion of disaster relief. This is about 0.025% of the total amount of spending in the bill (about one part in 4000 of the total). It is basically a rounding error difference compared to the scale of the total bill.
According to the Washington Post:

The original plan negotiated between House Speaker Mike Johnson
(R-Louisiana) and Democrats in both chambers ran more than 1,500
pages, while the legislation that the House voted down on Thursday was
just over 100 pages and dropped some policies unrelated to government
spending.  President-elect Donald Trump and his billionaire adviser
Elon Musk celebrated the smaller bill, arguing it avoided the
government waste they believed the bipartisan plan included, even
though both measures were expected to cost the federal government
roughly the same amount. Both measures would have kept the
government operating until mid-March and sent about $110 billion in
aid to victims of natural disasters and farmers. The revised bill
would also have suspended the federal borrowing limit for two years.

What in particular was changed (from the same source)?

A fix for stolen food stamp funds
One provision taken out of the initial bill was aimed at ensuring that
states replenish food stamp funds for Americans who rely on the
program whose benefits are stolen.
Starting in 2023, the federal government has reimbursed states that
provide benefits to the victims of food stamp theft. That measure is
set to expire on Friday. Since the reimbursement began, states have
reported paying $150 million in benefits to more than 300,000
households, according to Dottie Rosenbaum, an expert in the program at
the Center on Budget and Policy Priorities, a center-left think tank.
Pharmacy benefit overhaul
The original bill called for a series of changes to the operations of
pharmacy benefit managers — middlemen in the medicine business that
negotiate drug prices with pharmaceutical companies and help determine
what medications are covered by insurance firms. (Dropping these
provisions shaved hundreds of pages out of the legislation.) ...
RFK Stadium transfer
The original legislation included a provision that would transfer
control of the land in Washington, D.C., where RFK Stadium sits from
the federal government to the District government. That would have
enabled Mayor Muriel E. Bowser (D) to negotiate with the Washington
Commanders about a possible new stadium for the NFL team on the site
near the Anacostia River, moving from their current home in Maryland.
It also would let the District decide the future of the property even
without a new stadium deal.
Musk on Wednesday, before the provision was dropped, recirculated a
claim on X that the legislation included $3 billion for a new NFL
stadium in the District. The provision, however, included no new
federal funding — it even specifically banned the use of federal funds
for a new stadium.
Pay raises for members of Congress
The original legislation would have allowed a 3.8 percent
cost-of-living pay bump for lawmakers to take effect, which would
result in a pay raise of $6,600. They make $174,000 a year now. ...
Targeting ‘junk fees’
The original version of the spending package included two bipartisan
bills that aimed to crack down on so-called “junk fees,” specifically
by requiring ticket sellers and hotels to disclose any service charges
and other add-ons up front to customers, rather than waiting until the
end of the checkout process. ...
Childhood cancer research
The revised resolution dropped the Gabriella Miller Kids First
Research Act, which was named for a 10-year-old Virginia girl who died
from an inoperable brain tumor. The legislation was signed into law by
President Barack Obama, has historically drawn bipartisan support and
has put about $125 million toward childhood cancer research over the
past decade. The language in the now-abandoned resolution would have
reauthorized the program for another seven years. The House had passed
a version of it in March. ...
Criminalizing some ‘deepfake’ images
The revised legislation also jettisoned a bipartisan provision that
would have criminalized the publication of nonconsensual, intimate
images, known as revenge porn, as well as sexual images and videos
generated by artificial intelligence, called deepfakes.
The proposal would have also required social media sites to have
policies in place to remove such imagery.
Restrictions on investment in China
Congress was initially set to pass as part of the legislation a
measure restricting U.S. investments in China, expanding existing
rules currently being implemented by the Treasury Department. The
legislation also would have affirmed presidential authority to impose
economic sanctions on advanced technologies in China, according to the
American Action Forum, a center-right think tank.


Was there anything significant, ideology-wise?  For example, say there was transgender care $, of course that would be anathema to Republicans.  But most of this stuff seems fairly uncontroversial, except for food stamps, pay raise and possibly the fee disclosure stuff riling regulation averse Republicans.  OK, it seems the amended version went through, but that is a lot of brinkmanship for not much.  Except for the debt ceiling removal which ought to have been anathema to Republicans and never proposed.  Much ado about nothing, Rep-side, seems to me.  What was Musk mostly ranting about?

What was Musk's opposition motivated by? The last item, restrictions on investment in China. What did he say? Who knows. Read his ~150 tweets on the subject, if you really care. Most of the difference between the two bills (the original one that was negotiated vs the one that actually passed) was policy implementation details, which don't cost anything. The cost difference essentially amounts to the funds for childhood cancer research. Which unanimously passed the Senate several hours later, suggesting there's no partisan wedge on that issue. Nor was there ever one historically.

The talking points by the Mump Regime about the original vs. new bill is effectively that the new one has a significantly reduced number of pages. In other words, that it weighs less, when printed out on paper. As if that mattered at all when it comes to assessing legislation. Good policy regulations take space to spell out in detail. People who are serious about governing care about this. It is, in fact, more efficient to make the laws clear from the outset. Importantly, it doesn't increase the federal budget.

@CodyGray They didn't reduce the size by over 90% by removing details that add clarity. They slashed entire programs. This is all about small government, one of the basic principles of the Republican party.

@CodyGray You know, that would make for a good answer as well.  It's not exactly what I asked about, but if there is no great substance to the modified version of the budget compromise, as per this answer, which I will probably end up accepting later, then one wonders what the fuss was all about.  Trump picked it up and added the deficit ceiling suspension, but Musk started the ball rolling so it is a big piece of the puzzle.  Or, I could ask another question, asking only about what Musk had said, but I am unsure whether that's really necessary.

@Barmar: This answer’s summary seems to contradict the claim that the revisions “slashed entire programs” in any meaningful sense — most of the changes it lists are policy changes not programs, and the scale/cost of them all is tiny.  If you think that’s underselling the differences, and that the revisions genuinely advance the Republicans’ “small government” policy agenda, then that would be worth spelling out in a new answer.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I think it's not so much that it slashed programs as riders (correct term?) attached to the bill, that were laws/regulations, rather than budget items.  For example the revenge porn regulation/law? - that's not going to amount to much $, but may add many pages.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine "This answer’s summary seems to contradict the claim that the revisions “slashed entire programs” in any meaningful sense" When is anything that Trump claims true? There is nothing about the principles of the Republican party (except to make sure to deny people good health care and anything the helps poor people) at work here.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine It was poor wording. I just meant that it slashed large sections of the bill that weren't directly spending-related.
